# How to create a database on a Symfony2 based website using Doctrine?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

This seems like it should be pretty easy but I am running into problems trying to create a database following these instructions: http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/doctrine.html

I edit the parameters.yml and config.yml file and then run this command from terminal:

```
php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Could not create database for connection named `learn_symfony`
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

How do I resolve this error and create the database?

Comment: You seem to have entered the wrong password (or a password if it should be null) for your db connection.

Comment: I tried changing the password to null, but still run into the same problem

Comment: The password should't be set to null in your db connection config file. If you get "using password: YES", it means that password for root user exists and it is set in the database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are probably trying to connect on a server that isn't configured properly.

There is nothing to do with doctrine.

Tell me, are you trying to connect to a *home-made* server ? Is it a LAMP or WAMP stack ?

**EDIT**

If you are running on a recently installed server, you have to edit the MySQL configuration and set a password to the `root` account or set on the directive `allowNullPassword`

**EDIT 2**

If your server is *LAMP*, the file you have to change is located at `/etc/my.cnf`

**EDIT 3**
That file is for various mysql configurations. 
About the `allow null` i was mistaking with phpMyAdmin.
Try setting a password for the root with this command
`mysqladmin -u root password MYVERYNEWANDSECRETPASSWORD`

Comment: I am in the file /etc/mysql/my.cnf but I am not sure what I should be changing. I have added the utf defaults to this file but other than that....

Comment: Edited the answer. Don't forget to set the same password on your script. And don't forget **NEVER EVER USE ROOT ON PRODUCTION**